# Python multi-lists iteration

Tags: python, list, iteration

Is there a clever way to iterate over **two** lists in Python (without using *list comprehension*)?

I mean, something like this:

```
# (a, b) is the cartesian product between the two lists' elements
for a, b in list1, list2:
   foo(a, b)
```

instead of:

```
for a in list1:
    for b in list2:
        foo(a, b)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) does exactly this:

```
for a, b in itertools.product(list1, list2):
  foo(a, b)
```

It can handle an arbitrary number of iterables, and in that sense is more general than nested `for` loops.

Answer (score 0):

```
for a,b in zip(list1, list2):
    foo(a,b)
```

`zip` combines the elements of lists / arrays together element wise into tuples. e.g.

```
list1 = [1,2,5]
list2 = [-2,8,0]
for i in zip(list1,list2):
    print(i)
>>> (1, -2)
>>> (2, 8)
>>> (5, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use zip it allows you to zip two or more lists and iterate at a time.

```
list= [1, 2]
list2=[3,4]
combined_list = zip(list, list2)
for a in combined_list:
        print(a)
```